# Flask's request.files.getlist for isn't empty when field is not submitted

Tags: python, flask, form-data

I want to get a list of uploaded photos by using: `photos = request.files.getlist("photo")`. However, if I haven't selected any files in the browser, the `photos` value is not empty like other fields.

I want to check if no files are submitted by doing:

```
if not photos:
   pass
```

But there's always an empty `FileStorage` object even when no files are submitted:

```
request.files.getlist("photo")
[<FileStorage: '' ('application/octet-stream')>]
```

Why is it there? How can I check that no files were uploaded if the list is never empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.files` is populated with whatever the client submitted. Unfortunately, browsers submit file inputs even when no file is selected, which looks like a file with no name and no data. Neither a name or data is required to have a valid empty file, so it's left up to the app to decide what to do.

`FileStorage` will be considered `False` if it has no name. Flask-WTF considers a `FileStorage` with no name to be empty for validation.

```py
photo = request.files["photo"]

if not photo:
    # no photo
```

```py
photos = request.files["photo"].getlist()

if not photos or not any(f for f in photos):
    # no photos
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Empty File Storage Object, means if File field is left empty while submitting form and you are getting a empty file storage object ,and want to filter it.you can apply the below mentioned check.

```
if not (all(isinstance(item, FileStorage) for item in field.data) and 
         field.data and all((item.filename != '') for item in field.data)):
        return
```

for no files uploaded, FileStorage objects filename attribute is like field.data.file.filename = '', so that we can filter it based on this condition.